# Getting "socket hang up" using nodejs / socket.io and wscat

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have the following nodejs web socket server

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(8000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });


});

console.log("Listening on 8000");
```

When trying to connect using `wscat`

```
wscat -c ws://localhost:8000/
```

I get the following error

```
error: Error: socket hang up
```

It works just fine in browser with the following javascript

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
socket.on('news', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: did you ever get this working ? I have the same problem

Answer (score 20):

I suggest that you try connecting to endpoint while specifying transport protocol. Like this:

```
wscat -c ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/\?transport=websocket
```

This works for my case.

Comment: If the last line of output is `< 40`, `"event-name"` event with `"new message"` message can be emitted with the following command
`> 42["event-name","new message"]`