# Docker nginx reverse proxy gives "502 Bad Gateway"

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy

I'm trying to have a docker container with nginx work as reverse proxy to other docker containers and I keep getting "Bad Gateway" on locations other other than the base location '/'.

I have the following server block:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass "http://game2048:8080";
  }

  location /game {
    proxy_pass "http://game:9999";
  }

}
```

It works for `http://localhost` but not for `http://localhost/game` which gives "Bad Gateway" in the browser and this on the nginx container:

```
[error] 7#7: *6 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) 
while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: , 
request: "GET /game HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.4:9999/game", 
host: "localhost"
```

I use the official nginx docker image and put my own configuration on it. You can test it and see all details here:
https://github.com/jollege/ngprox1

Any ideas what goes wrong?

NB: I have set local hostname entries on docker host to match those names:

```
127.0.1.1       game2048
127.0.1.1       game
```

Comment: Now that I post it, I see that the path "game" is passed on to the upstream server, that part should not be passed on. Any ideas how to handle that? Btw, in the scenario I want to use it for, I want it to proxy to different services based on the incoming server name / http header.

Comment: I was using the wrong port.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I fixed it! I set the server name in different server blocks in nginx config. Remember to use docker port, not host port.

```
server {

  listen 80;
  server_name game2048;

  location / {
    proxy_pass "http://game2048:8080";
  }

}

server {

  listen 80;
  server_name game;

  location / {
    # Remember to refer to docker port, not host port
    # which is 9999 in this case:
    proxy_pass "http://game:8080";
  }

}
```

The github repo has been updated to reflect the fix, the old readme file is there under `./README.old01.md`.

Typical that I find the answer when I carefully phrase the question to others. Do you know that feeling?

Comment: Stackoverflow is great for [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :)

Comment: Indeed! I hadn't heard that term before - but man, do I know the concept!

Comment: "Remember to use docker port, not host port." Saved me. Thanks.

Comment: lol guys...that valid for me too, I know what's rubber duck debugging :-D

Comment: REMEMBER TO USE DOCKER PORT, NOT THE HOST PORT. That's the point. I wasted hours because of using a bad port number. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I'm confused you said to use port 9999 in the comment but still use 8080 in the proxy_pass line?

Comment: Sorry @Amon, it's nearly 6 years ago, I can't remember. I know that I made it work as described above. I don't work actively with my own docker containers anymore (I use other people's containers).

Answer (score 11):

I had the same "502 Bad Gateway" error, but the solution was to tune proxy_buffer_size following [this post](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/tuning-proxy_buffer_size-in-nginx) instructions:

```
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_buffer_size 16k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 24k;
proxy_buffers 64 4k;
```

Comment: How to do this with a docker image?

Comment: That was exactly what fixed all my problems with reverse proxy nginx! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

See the nginx error log

```
sudo tail -n 100 /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

If you see Permission denied error in the log like below -

> 2022/03/28 03:51:09 [crit] 1140954#0: *141 connect() to
> xxx.xxx.68.xx:8080 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to
> upstream, client: xxx.xx.xxx.25, server: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

See whether the value of `httpd_can_network_connect` is enabled or not by running the command: `sudo getsebool -a | grep httpd`

If you see the value of `httpd_can_network_connect` is `off` then this is the cause of your issue.

Solution:
set the value of `httpd_can_network_connect` is `on` by run the command `sudo setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on -P`

Hope it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

For me helped this line of code `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;`

```
location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass http://myserver;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, but for a web application that was just not serving at the IP and port mentioned in the config.

So say you have this:

```
location /game {
    proxy_pass "http://game:9999";
}
```

Then make sure the web application that you expect at http://game:9999 is really serving from within a docker container named 'game' and the code is set to serve the app at port 9999.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, after 4 hours, only I missed put the port with semanage command.

```
 location / {
            proxy_pass http://A.B.C.D:8090/test;
  }
```

The solution was add 8090 port and works.

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t  -p tcp 8090
```

Comment: You save my day! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Docker networking. The `proxy_pass` needs to **use the Docker service name** (as defined in your compose.yaml file, and not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare an external network if the container you are pointing to is defined in another ***docker-compose.yml*** file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:1.17.4-alpine
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-webserver
    depends_on:
      - drupal
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./docroot:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - internal
      - my-passwords

networks:
  my-passwords:
    external: true
    name: my-passwords_default
```

***nginx.conf***:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     test2.com www.test2.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://my-passwords:3000/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to telnet on the upstream machine to check to wither it's connected:
tracing the `/var/log/nginx/error.log` would help.

Answer (score 0):

As this was seen in my setup just recently, i had to downgrade connexion in requirements.txt to pre 3.x version for this work. This is related to: [Nginx upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, for large requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488688/nginx-upstream-prematurely-closed-connection-while-reading-response-header-from)

```
#connexion[flask,swagger-ui,uvicorn]
connexion[swagger-ui]==2.14
flask==2.2.3
```