# docker nginx reverse proxy to gitlab container with built-in nginx give Connection refused

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup a local env using Nginx container as reverse proxy to Jfrog container and Gitlab (with Nginx build in enabled) container, I can access the artifactory container through the Nginx (reverse proxy) but when I'm trying to access the Gitlab container through the Nginx (revrese proxy) I get Connection Refused error.

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```
upstream gitlab {
    server git.dev.local:8000;
} 
upstream jfrog {
    server jfrog.dev.local:8082;
}

server {
    server_name git.dev.local;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://gitlab;
    }
}

server { 
    server_name jfrog.dev.local;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://jfrog;
    }
}
```

**Notes**:

- set Gitlab exteranl_url to "git.dev.local".
- I can access the `git.dev.local:8000` directly without any issues.
- the jfrog mapped from port 8082 to 8082 and gitlab from 8000 to 80.
- the Jfrog is accessible using the nginx reverse proxy without any issues.
- the Nginx (reverse proxy), Gitlab and Jfrog containers all attached to custom network with their host names.

  - `docker network connect --alias jfrog.dev.local general-network jfrog`
  - `docker network connect --alias git.dev.local general-network gitlab`

```
[error] 42 42: *111 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.48.1, server: git.dev.local, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.2:8000/", host: "git.dev.local"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing reverse proxy using nginx container, I should forward the port to **the docker port not host port** as the answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091356/docker-nginx-reverse-proxy-gives-502-bad-gateway?rq=2#answer-47091862). thanks for Jollege answer.