# Nginx multiple servers with subdomains

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a node server running on port `4000` and postgres running on `5432` on a GCP VM. I want to be able to access the node server at `api.mydomain.com` and postgres at `db.mydomain.com`.

I'm able to access the server at the desired subdomain with the SSL cert, but I'm getting a "502 Bad Gateway" for the db endpoint.

To configure the `server` block for the db, I copied over the one for the server and had certbot generate the necessary ssl certificate.

Here's the config in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
    server_name api.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = api.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    server_name api.mydomain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    server_name db.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5432;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/db.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/db.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = db.mydomain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    server_name db.mydomain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Both resources are available

[image]

Comment: What is the corresponding message from the nginx error log?

Comment: Error log:  https://gist.github.com/chriskrogh/b0fd94c3d1b883908b294f3d45ed1fb7

Not sure how to interpret what's going on. @IvanShatsky

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488688/nginx-upstream-prematurely-closed-connection-while-reading-response-header-from) thread. If you need to proxy both HTTP and WebSocket connections to your DB backend, try the second method from the [official docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) (that one using `map` block).

Comment: I eventually gave up on that config. I ended up connecting to postgres outside of nginx.