# Shiny server fails to download large PDF files

Tags: nginx, shiny

My shiny app, running on an aws EC2 instance with 8 GB RAM, does some analysis fine, and generates a lot of plots. I have a downloadHandler() that prints all these plots into a pdf for download. This all works fine locally (and on RStudio server on the same instance), but not when on shiny server.

If the PDF is small (say it contains only one plot), then it downloads fine. However, when the PDF is larger it downloads an html file called plot_pdfs.html (the name of the downloadHandler is output$plot_pdfs), which contains the text

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

There are no errors in the shiny-server logs at these locations

```
var/log/shiny-server.log
var/log/shiny-server/romeo-shiny-20230928-210724-38219.log
```

What I do keep seeing every time I try and download this large PDF is this error in the nginx error log (`var/log/nginx/error.log`)

```
2023/09/28 21:24:59 [error] 16809#16809: *55 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 86.141.185.175, server: michaelflower.org, request: "GET /romeo/session/0bfa7408352fc29f746eb761f0d899b9/download/plot_pdfs?w= HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3838/romeo/session/0bfa7408352fc29f746eb761f0d899b9/download/plot_pdfs?w=", host: "michaelflower.org", referrer: "https://michaelflower.org/romeo/"
```

I found a few posts about this, including:

> [Nginx upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, for large requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488688/nginx-upstream-prematurely-closed-connection-while-reading-response-header-from)

However, none of the suggestions resolved my problems.

This is my nginx configuration file (`etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`):

```
 map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
  }

  server {
    server_name michaelflower.org www.michaelflower.org;
    location /rstudio/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8787/;
             proxy_redirect http://localhost:8787/ $scheme://$host/rstudio/;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
             proxy_read_timeout 20d;
         
    }

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
      proxy_redirect / $scheme://$http_host/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
       proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
       proxy_connect_timeout 10080s;
       proxy_send_timeout 10080;
       proxy_read_timeout 10080;
       proxy_buffer_size 64k;
       proxy_buffers 16 32k;
       proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_request_buffering off;
       proxy_buffering on;
       proxy_max_temp_file_size 4096m;
    }
  
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/michaelflower.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/michaelflower.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
 
  server {
    if ($host = www.michaelflower.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = michaelflower.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
   
    listen 80;
    server_name michaelflower.org www.michaelflower.org;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

And this is my shiny server configuration file (`etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`):

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir var/log/shiny-server; # I had to remove the '/' infant of var as stack didn't like it

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;

    app_init_timeout 600;
    app_idle_timeout 3600;

  }
}
```

**So a bit more progress ...**

I made a test app - https://michaelflower.org/pdf/. It tests inserting n number of plots into a PDF, either within the downloadHandler itself, or outside the downloadHandler, and then downloading.

It turns out that if the PDF generation is done inside the downloadHandler, it works for 50 plots (144kb), but fails at 75 plots (produces an html file containing "502 Bad Gateway, nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)").

However, if you generate the PDFs outside the downloadHandler, it can download even 5000 plots (14.1 Mb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem seems to be the downloadHandler, which can't handle generating large files. However, if you generate the pdf file outside the downloadHandler, then it works.

I made a test app - https://michaelflower.org/pdf/. It tests inserting n number of plots into a PDF, either within the downloadHandler itself, or outside the downloadHandler, and then downloading.

It turns out that if the PDF generation is done inside the downloadHandler, it works for 50 plots (144kb), but fails at 75 plots (produces an html file containing "502 Bad Gateway, nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)").

However, if you generate the PDFs outside the downloadHandler, it can download even 5000 plots (14.1 Mb)